# Reading Docker metrics in machine readable format

Tags: docker, metrics

I'm running some Docker containers for my users. Users are able to start and stop their containers dynamically, so I would like to watch my **Data space available** metrics from `docker info` with some sort of monitoring system.

I've tried to use Docker API directory with

```sh
echo -e 'GET /info HTTP/1.0\r\n' |  nc -U /var/run/docker.sock | grep '{'  | python -m json.tool
```

but the result is returned in human readable units - ie. "16.93 MB" and "9 GB", which is not suitable for machine processing.

The same happens when using Python Docker API library.

```
import docker
client = docker.Client()
print(client.info()['DriverStatus'])
```

So the question is: Is there a machine-readable version of `docker info` for for parsing out "Base Data Space Total" metrics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could use [`docker info --format '{{json .}}'`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/info/#run-docker-info-on-windows).

For example:

```
user@host$ docker info --format '{{json .MemTotal}}'
3840544768
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It  doesn't work on my testing machine, because `--format` flag is not defined in Docker engine 1.12 (on CentOS 7). 

It seems to be working from Docker 1.13.